# Query to select rows with a date within certain periods of time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that will select all rows with a date in the `due` column where its 15 mins, 10 mins and 5 mins until the `due` timestamp and then also if its been 15 minutes since the timestamp in the `last_reminder` column

```
SELECT a.* FROM tasks a WHERE 
    a.due <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND a.status = '' AND 
    (
        due > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE OR 
        due > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE OR 
        due > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE OR 
        last_reminder <= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). ' - 15 minutes'))."'
    )
```

This query returns all rows whether the time is within 5, 10 or 15 minutes or not

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement isn't perfectly clear.

But this is clear. This filter clause

```
    due > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE OR 
    due > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE OR 
    due > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Is the logical equivalent of this one.

```
    due > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

Also, I think you want this

```
last_reminder <= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). ' - 15 minutes'))."
```

to turn into this SQL

```
last_reminder <= '2019-01-23-06:45' - INTERVAL 15 minutes
```

I *think* you forgot "INTERVAL".

Also, you probably want the php expression `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. That retrieves your current datestamp just as effectively as the one you used. Or, you could just use SQL's `NOW()` and get this much simpler query.

```
last_reminder <= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 minutes
```

To meet your 15/10/5 requirement maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT IF(due>NOW()-INTERVAL 15 MINUTE AND due<=NOW()-INTERVAL 10 MINUTE, 'yes', 'no') ago15,
       IF(due>NOW()-INTERVAL 10 MINUTE AND due<=NOW()-INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, 'yes', 'no') ago10,
       IF(due>NOW()-INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, 'yes', 'no') ago5,
       a.*
  FROM ...
```

This gives you three extra columns showing whether your row is in the  15, 10, or 5 minute category.

To troubleshoot the timing stuff, you can add this to the SELECT clause:

```
 TIMEDIFF(NOW(), due) AS how_long_until_due,
```

It will, for each row, show you how long until each item is due.

Comment: just tested this, and at 12:08 where the due column was 12:15 it showed ago5 was yes but it wasn't quite 5 minutes until 12:15. i'm trying to have the query send a reminder email when the due timestamp is 5, 10 and 5 minutes away

Comment: Troubleshooting this timing stuff can be tricky. See the last few lines I just added to my answer.